# I need Clarification on Azure App Registration

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I need to Register an App in the Azure Portal in order to retrieve a Token for my Windows Desktop application.

Do I select **Web App / API** or **Native**?

APPLICATION DETAILS
The main application is a Windows Desktop Executable. It does NOT run on a handheld device (e.g. SmartPhone) NOR is a web browser involved.

We've created a type library using EWS Managed API in order to create appointments directly in Exchange (we use Exchange On Line).  Now we'd like to use OAuth APIs for Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Use Native. It corresponds to OAuth2 public client concept - an application that cannot use/protect secrets. Use WebApp/API for Confidential Clients, e.g. web apps (except SPA), batch services running in protected environments, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  Your definition also helped me refine my search and find helpful documentation:  [v1 App Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app)